# Angular: block a route after activating it

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am working on an Angular app where I have a login page in my dashboard component. I am showing a set of data in my table component. I have successfully blocked the table route which the user cannot access until he has logged in. What I want to do is that after the user has logged in in the dashboard component, I want to block the dashboard component so that the user cannot access the login section again until he has logged out, which is my third component. I have tried doing that below but it's not working. Here's my code:

> admin-layout.routing.ts

```
export const AdminLayoutRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'dashboard', canActivate: [RoleGuard],     component: DashboardComponent },
{ path: 'user',           component: UserComponent },
{ path: 'table',  canActivate: [AuthGuard],        component: TableComponent },
{ path: 'icons',          component: IconsComponent }
];
```

> auth-guard.service.ts //for the protection of my table component

```
constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router){}

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean
  {
   if(this.authService.isAuthenticated())
    {
      return true;
    }
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');
    return false;
  }
```

> role-guard.service.ts //for the protection of my dashboard component(login page)

```
constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthService){}

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) : boolean
{
  if(this.authService.isNotAuthenticated)
  {
    console.log("role guard True cond."); //this gets printed on console always, even after I login

    return true;
  }
  console.log("role guard false cond.")
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/table');
  return false;
}
```

> auth.service.ts //for defining the logic of the above two guards

```
 export class AuthService
 {
 loggedIn:boolean = false;

 check_Authentication(logIn : boolean)
 {
  if(logIn == true)
  {
    this.loggedIn = true;
  }
  else
  {
    this.loggedIn = false;
  }
 }

isAuthenticated()
{
 if(this.loggedIn == true)
 {
   return true;
 }
 else
 {
   return false;
 }
}

isNotAuthenticated()
{
 if(this.loggedIn != true)
 {
   return true;
 }
 else
 {
   return false;
 }
}

}
```

> dashboard.component.ts //I am sending the variable as true if the user has logged in, here

```
private onAuthorization(form: NgForm)
{
  this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/auth', form.value, {responseType: "text"})
  .subscribe(responseData =>{
    console.log(responseData);
    if(responseData == "Successfully Authorized")
    {
      this.auth_check = true;
      this.authService.check_Authentication(this.auth_check);
      if(this.authService.isAuthenticated)
      {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/table');
      }
    }
    else
    {
      this.auth_failed = true;
    }

  }
  ,error => {
    this.connectionToServer = false;
  });
  this.connectionToServer = true;
}
```

Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong? EDIT: The login page isn't getting blocked after I navigate the user to the table page, which it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw your code, you can use three helper `methods`  and store the state of the user in `localStorage` on successful login,  on logout remove the state(token). and the third one is `getState(): boolean` for determining the user state.

1. set `state` on successfully  log in

```
private saveState(token: string): void {
  localStorage.setItem('state', 'true');
  this.token = token;
}
```

2)Remove `state` on log Out and

```
logout(){
      localStorage.removeItem('token');
      this.router.navigate(['/login'])
}
```

3)Verify the user by its `state` and do your work on the basis of `true` and `false` response

```
 private getState(): boolean {
      let token = localStorage.getItem('state');
      if(token){
        return true;
      }
      else {
        return false;
      }
```

Comment: thanks, I will definitely look into this  :)

Comment: @MuhammadHassan You are welcome, and if you need further info i am here to help.

Comment: Much appreciated. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked your code, after you login you need to set a value into your localstorage that can be accessible from any service.

for example:

```
if(responseData === "Successfully Authorized")
{
    localStorage.setItem('loggedIn', true);
}
```

In your auth guard, you just need to check if the localstorage has value or not, it would be something like this

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean
{
   let isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem('loggedIn');
   if (isLoggedIn) {
      return true;
   }
   this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');
   return false;
}
```

Need to do this in your Role Guard

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) : boolean
{
  const isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem('loggedIn');
  if(!isLoggedIn)
  {
    console.log("role guard True cond."); //this gets printed on console always, even after I login
    return true;
  }
  console.log("role guard false cond.");
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/table');
  return false;
}
```

Hopefully it helps. thanks

Comment: I see, then for this, there's no need of adding an auth.service.ts. :)

Comment: auth.service.ts you can use to call the api that you have in your dashboard.component.ts. that one is the better approach.

Comment: that's not the issue. The login page isn't getting blocked after I navigate the user to the table page, which it should.

Comment: you need to add checker on your ngOnInit on your login page, if user login or not. When user already login, then you can redirect them to the default page after login. let me update my answer

Comment: I have redirected the user to the table route after he successfully logs in, which is working correctly. What is not working is that after I navigate the user to the table section then the user shouldn't be able to access the login (default) page until he has logged out.

Comment: just add the changes, in the last section. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was making a simple mistake and it worked perfectly for me.

Everything remained the same except

> role-guard.service.ts //for the protection of my dashboard component(login page)

```
constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthService){}

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) : boolean
{
  if(this.authService.isNotAuthenticated()) //I was missing parenthesis in my function 
                                            //call here
  {
  console.log("role guard True cond."); //this gets printed on console always, even 
                                        //after I login

  return true;
  }
 console.log("role guard false cond.")
 this.router.navigateByUrl('/table');
 return false;
 }
```